# How to get form elements from multiple forms in a single page

Tags: forms, get, element

Using below code I can get form element types, names and values,

```
var items = $("form :input").map(function(index, elm) {
    return {name: elm.name, type:elm.type, value: $(elm).val()};
});
```

I have multiple forms in a single page and I want to identify the form elements of each form based on the **form name** or **form id**.
For example,

```
<form name="test" method="post" id="test" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

        <input type="checkbox" name="chekbox">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" >
        <textarea>test</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">     
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <input type="submit" name="search">
    </form>
    <form name="test2" id="test2">
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <input type="radio" name="a" value="a"><input type="radio" name="a" value="b">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chekbox">
        <input type="submit" name="search">
    </form>
```

I need the form elements of form name **test** and form name **test2** separately.